# How to write a client socket that will listen in the background already having created?

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

First of all i am fairly new to this i have server/client socket in action and the server is sending/receiving data but my client at the moment is only sending data in a try/catch block and i need to write a another method to just catch the incoming data?
and to keep it outside my original try/ctach*

Any help would be great

```
public void onClick(View v)
         {
             setMyIp(ipaddress.getText().toString());
            // myComs.sending_data(getMyIp() , "Got connected");
            try
             {
                 InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(getMyIp());
                 Socket s = new Socket(inet, 2000);
                 OutputStream o = s.getOutputStream();
                 PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(o);
                 InputStream in = s.getInputStream();


                 p.println("You are connected");
                 p.flush();

                 readContacts();
                 //inboxConversations();
                 //outboxConversations();
                 readSms();


             }
             catch (UnknownHostException e) 
             {
                ipaddress.setText("Unknown host");
                   e.printStackTrace();
             }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }


     });
```

This is my code and i need to create a separate listener outside of the button any idea

**Thank you**

---

Comment: It sounds like you want [multiple threads](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/extending-thread-class-multithreading-concepts.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to keep the socket opened in a loop constantly listening for any data to write.  Do this on a seperate thread/process of course.  Actually both server and client side should be on a seperate thread in my opinion.  You can look up java NIO, but here is some code  JUST TO GET YOU STARTED, as android has a class that can do things in the background and update the main UI afterwards its called ASYNCHTASK.  you can spawn a thread in other ways of course just showing you a convenient way:
(note i havent ran this i just wrote it how i would do it so it take it as pseudo code)

```
class ClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> // or whatever you want to pass in
{

        public static String ip = "10.0.2.1";
        public static int port = 5061;
        Socket socket;
        public DataInputStream dis;
        public DataOutputStream dos;
        public String message;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


/* set up our socket and open a stream to read */

                 try {
                socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));           

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("AsyncTank class", "Socket has some trouble opening");
            }

/*heres the stuff your looking for to listen to a socket all day long*/

while(socket.isConnected()){
                String mymessage=dis.readLine(); //readline blocks
/* do something with your message */    
publishProgress(mymessage); //publishes update to main UI thread            
                        }
                }

            }
            return null;
        }



@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... messages) {

     Toast.makeText(this, messages,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //announce updates on incoming socket

}


}
```

-------- if you dont need to update the main UI after the sockets closed for any reason just do the same thing but use a runnable or Thread class to create and listen.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a client to act as a receiver you have run a thread for this asynchronous behaviour else it will freeze your application if you do it on main thread.

So do the following thing

in your client's main method start a receiver thread

```
Thread receiver_thread=new Thread(new Reciever());
reciever_thread.start();
```

Here is the receiver class

```
public class Receiver implements Runnable  
{
    public void run()  
    {
        While(true)
        {
            //check here if there is some data in your input stream so what              
               //you receive when server sends something to you

           //so that's it here  do your work with the incoming data
           //suggestion make an inner class to your main ui class so that data that comes here can be printed to those ui components.
         }
      }
}
```

hope it helps you